# Separating external jars from plugin lib direcory

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a plugin that depends on external jar files.
I've made an update site to install the plugin into any eclipse.

These external jar files are shipped with the plugin.

I want to separate these external dependencies so that the plugin needs them during the installation and get them at the installation time. or search for them in a specific location away from the plugin jar file

Is that possible? 
If so, How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create separate plug-in's for each of the external jar's?

Like the way Eclipse handles things like Apache components.